# Can you use multiple VaryByCustom parameters when caching a user control?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I've been trying this a couple of different ways, but it's not working for some reason. Is  it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Separate them in your declaration by semicolons.

Comment: How is separating them by semicolon is different than comma, period or any other special character?

Comment: Downvoted, because using a semicolon won't give you support for multiple parameters. If you want this, you should implement it yourself.

Comment: Agreed with @Richard; this does _not_ give automatic support.

Answer (score 4):

If you are overriding GetVaryByCustomString() in the Global.asax.cs file, you can pass in a semicolon delimited list of values which you then need to parse.

There is one built-in value (Browser) which will be used if the attribute specified does not exist.

Comment: Technically, though, if one is overriding `GetVaryByCustomString`, can't one pass the list of customs in any format, since one will have to do its own parsing anyway? Or will it matter for a call to `base.GetVaryByCustomString` inside the overridden implementation?

Comment: @bzlm `base.GetVaryByCustomString` doesn't implement any string splitting capabilities and will only do something when `browser` is passed as a value. This means you can choose any character as your separator.

Comment: Technically the delimiter doesn't matter. However, Microsoft recommends using a semicolon in their documentation. Also, semicolon is supported automatically for VaryByParam and usually it is wise to stick with a convention, if one is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple parameters by separating them by a semicolon, but you have to implement the logic of splitting them yourself. **This means you can use any character as your separator, because you need to parse it yourself.**

You probably overriding `GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)` in your global.asax. The `custom` parameter will contain anything you pass using `VaryByCustom`, like this

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="none" VaryByCustom="custom1;custom2" %>
```

*Extra note: `base.GetVaryByCustomString` doesn't implement any string splitting capabilities and will only do something when `browser` is passed as a value. Otherwise it will return `null`.*